# Move div with user scroll

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to achieve an "animation" that works with a user scrolls. I have two divs that are positioned how I want them to. But I want a fourth div to essentially operate as a fixed element to create the illusion of lines 'growing' on scroll. But I want this fixed element within a relatively position parent div.

This is hard to explain without code, so take a look at this CodePen. It should be more clear. Please let me know if I can provide more info. Thanks in advance!

https://codepen.io/summeropratt/pen/ExPmodO

```css
    body {
      height: 1200px;
    }
    .main-parent {
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .data {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    .size {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .data-lines {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0px;
    }

    .animation-parent {
      position: relative;
    }
    .data-overlay {
      background-color: #000;
      z-index: 2;
      height: 90px; 
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="main-parent">
      <div class="animation-parent">
        <div class="data-overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="data">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      </div>
      <div class="data-lines">
        <img class="size" src="https://i.ibb.co/tDMMgmv/lines.png">
      </div>
      <div class="data">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      </div>
    </div>
```